# Getting the detail-namespace code out of sight - elegantly

Tags: c++, idioms, forward-declaration

Suppose I'm writing a header-only or header-mostly library, and have the following code:

```cpp
using my_type = int;

namespace detail {
    inline void foo() { my_type x; do_foo_stuff(x); }
}

inline void bar() { do_bar_stuff(); detail::foo(); }
inline void baz(my_type y) { do_baz_stuff(y); detail::foo(); }
```

I want to place `foo()` in a different file. The motivation is that I have lots of such in-detail and out-of-detail functions, and I want the header with my public API to not be cluttered by what appears within `detail`, and is not intended for direct use.

The question is - what's an idiomatic way to do this?

- I can't just include a file with the `detail::` code at the *end* of my public header - since the declarations need to be made by the time they're used.
- I can't just include a file with the `detail::` code at the *beginning* of my public header - since they rely on some public definitions, e.g. types and constants. Let's assume they don't rely on any *functions* though.

So it can't be one of these two options.

Comment: What if you make it as good as possible without thinking of making it header-only and see the header-only-step as a possible improvement? I don't think you'll loose much usability by making it into a compiled library anyway so I'm perhaps biased :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'm already committed to header-mostly for various reasons. But it's a fair comment generally.

Comment: If what's in detail relies on some public definitions of types and constants, shouldn't those types and constant be included as a separate header?

Comment: @Bob__: They could; but then, the user reading the API will need to be looking at two files at the same time - the file with `my_type` and the file with `bar`, `baz` and other functions.

Comment: Would declaring bar and baz, and defining them in a second header with the rest of the details suffice? Assuming this second header is included at the bottom of your library header

Comment: It wouldn't really help much, I'd still be keeping a large fraction of the "noise" of a detail namespace.

Comment: I think that depends on whether you are happy to have the impl hidden away or if you need the impl available (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

Because usually headers contain declarations and source files contain implementation people get the idea that headers are interfaces, public api's, while source files contain implementation detail. This is further reinforced by the fact that in a library the user (consumer of the library) doesn't see the contents of the source files, but can see the headers.

This is however false:

- headers do contain definitions (templates, inline functions and variables),
- headers contain declarations of private class members and symbols with internal linkage (static non-locals and anonymous namespaces). This is clearly not part of the API in any way.
- a library will expose a symbol (class, function) even if it is used exclusively internally and is not part of the API (unless it is used on only one CU and made with internal linkage)
- a library header will bring in the consumer code all the header it uses, even if some of those headers are not needed for the library API. This will bring unneeded symbols in the user code, cluttering the namespaces.

The separation of headers and source files isn't done at the public interface / implementation barrier. This code separation is just an artifact of how C++ with its C heritage is designed. C++ doesn't require a a multi-pass compiler so it requires declaration before use and one definition. So headers are a solution for this. They are not API specifications.

So the unfortunate conclusion is that C++ does not have a API / implementation separation and trying to use headers for that will be unsuccessful.

Now to answer your question: The idiomatic way that I know is indeed to use a `details` or `impl` namespace. It's understood that a namespaces named this way contains library implementation details and should not be used in the user code. I personally would not change your initial design.

---

C++20 finally brings in modules, which afaik solves this issue. And now we have a clear separation of internal symbols that will not be seen in the consumer vs the public API.

Comment: Your answer isn't really an answer. I already am using a `detail` sub-namespace This question is about how and where to place its contents. As for C++20 modules - I won't be able to rely on them until a good few years after C++ 2020 is out and adoption spreads.

Comment: @einpoklum I thought I answered your question: "The motivation is that I have lots of such in-detail and out-of-detail functions, and I want the header with my public API to not be cluttered by what appears within detail, and is not intended for direct use." My answer is that you can't have a header with public API so just keep it as it is. Anyways, that's my two cents. It's just a pov you might consider. As for the modules, yes, I know the implementation is not here yet, that's why their mention is separated from the rest of the answer, more of a footnote. I thought it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require the "public api" implementation to be in the main header, and are happy with just the function signatures, you can split the declarations into the main header and the definitions into the detail header like so:

```
//header.hpp
using my_type = int;

inline my_type bar();
inline my_type baz(my_type y);

#include "detail.hpp"
```

```
// detail.hpp
#include <cstdlib>
namespace detail {
    inline my_type foo(my_type i) { return std::rand() + i; }
}

inline my_type bar() { return detail::foo(3); }
inline my_type baz(my_type y) { return detail::foo(y); }
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << bar() << " "<< baz(4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc 11.3

```bash
$ g++ -std=gnu++14 main.cpp -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic && ./a.out
1804289386 846930890
```

Answer (score 0):

My current idea is to do both a start-of-file and end-of-file inclusion of the same header, and instead of giving it an include guard, using a two-time-inclusion mechanism, with the first inclusion exposing declarations, and the second exposing definitions, e.g. something like:

```
#ifndef MY_DETAIL_HPP_TWICE
#ifndef MY_DETAIL_HPP_ONCE
#define MY_DETAIL_HPP_ONCE
#else
#define DEFINITIONS_VISIBLE
#define MY_DETAIL_HPP_TWICE
#endif // MY_DETAIL_HPP_ONCE

namespace detail {

inline void foo()
#ifndef DEFINITIONS_VISIBLE
;
#else
{ my_type x; do_foo_stuff(x); }
#endif

}
#endif // MY_DETAIL_HPP_TWICE
```

but this seems rather contrived, and I haven't seen that used anywhere.

Comment: or maybe two different header files: detail_decl.h and detail_impl.h ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: That's a possibility. It will have a lot of code duplication, though, won't it? Anyway, you could make that an answer, see what the vox populi favors :-)

Comment: I don;t know if it is a good idea or not - I haven't seen a scenario where anyone did what you are trying to do...  If you do find a solution that you do like I would be interested to see it.